# $\mathbf{r}(t):=(t^3,t^7)$. I want to say $(1,0)$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve defined by $\mathbf{r}$ at $\mathbf{0}$. Why bad?

Tags: curves, tangent-line

> The vector $\mathbf{r}'(t)$ is called the **tangent vector** to the curve defined by $\mathbf{r}$ at the point $\mathbf{r}(t)$, provided that $\mathbf{r}'(t)$ exists and $\mathbf{r}'(t)\neq\mathbf{0}$.

[image]

Let $\mathbf{r}(t):=(t^3,t^7)$.
Then, $\mathbf{r}'(0)=\mathbf{0}$.
So, the tangent vector to the curve defined by $\mathbf{r}$ at the point $\mathbf{r}(0)$ is not defined.

$\mathbf{r}'(t)=(3t^2,7t^6)$.
Suppose $\epsilon$ is a nonzero real number whose absolute value is very small.
$\mathbf{r}'(\epsilon)=(3\epsilon^2,7\epsilon^6)=3\epsilon^2(1,\frac{7}{3}\epsilon^4)\approx 3\epsilon^2(1,0)$ since $\epsilon^2\ll\epsilon^4$.
So, I want to say $(1,0)$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve defined by $\mathbf{r}$ at the point $\mathbf{r}(0)$.

Why is my idea bad?

Comment: If using approximations, the derivative should say that $\mathbf{r}(h) \approx \mathbf{r}(0) + h\mathbf{r}'(0)$, and that's not what you've done.  You're trying to say that $\mathbf{r}'(0)$ is roughly something.

Comment: Your idea makes sense. Notice that a different parametrization of the same curve is $r(t)=(t,t^{7/3})$. I don't think the definition you quoted means that there is no tangent vector if $r'(t)=0$, it just means the derivative is not considered a tangent vector in that case.

Comment: @Randall Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Karl Thank you very much for your comment.